# What to do when my answer was supposed to be only an alternative to another one, but outvotes it?

Tags: discussion, answers, voting

I occasionally stumble upon questions where there is already an answer **A** that solves the particular given problem just fine, but I feel it's useful to also point out some alternative approach **B**. **B** may be more efficient, more general or just more quirky/“clever”, anyway I don't mean to say it's actually a better solution, just one that's *also good to know about*.
Sometimes **B** will actually be a good deal more complicated than **A**, so I would rather recommend **A**.

Yet, these answers often turn out to be quite popular with the peer reviewers, and end up with more votes than **A**. (**A** was perhaps “boring”, while **B** is somewhat interesting even for experienced programmers of the tagged language).
So if the OP didn't already accept **A** earlier, **B** then shows up on top, and I have to assume somebody who finds the question from a search engine will try **B** first.

But I didn't actually intend that! I want the simple, easy to understand solution to come first, so somebody who needs quick help gets just that, and **A** was just fine. **B** was only targeted for those who want to delve deeper, as supplementary information.

So what should I do?

- I could of course repost **A** on top of my own answer, but even with attribution I feel this is unfair and likely grabbing off rep from the author of **A**.
- I could delete my answer and edit **B** to the bottom of the **A** answer. But I don't find this quite right either: **B** *is*, after all, a complete solution to the problem too, and doesn't really belong to **A**.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Put such a notice on the very top of your answer: (source is available if you click "edit")

> **This is an alternative to [link to other answer here], please try that other answer first.**
>
> ---

Most people will notice this, some might even click the link to the other answer.

Other than that, not much you can, or should, do. You should not ask people not to upvote, or to upvote the other answer instead.

Comment: "You should not ask people not to upvote" Who in the right mind would ask that?

Comment: @dorukayhan well, some people care more about the overall content than their own reputation - rare, but it happens. :)